# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getRatio()

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getRatio() must be of the
>   type integer, string given, called in
>   /Users/mpxq2/Projects/server/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php
>   on line 155 and defined in
>   /Users/mpxq2/Projects/server/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php
>   on line 92
>
> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::getRatio() must be of the
>   type integer, string given, called in
>   /Users/mpxq2/Projects/server/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php
>   on line 155 in
>   /Users/mpxq2/Projects/server/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageFactory.php
>   on line 92

I'm trying to open any category page and getting this errors. Just updated to 2.3.0. setup:upgrade, static-content:deploy, setup:di:compile, cache:flush and indexer:reindex already done... How can i solve this?

Comment: delete the generated folder and clean the cache

Comment: @GeeEmm didn't help

Comment: @dukir have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

this file use

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/opengraph/general.phtml

```
        <?php
            /**
            * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
            * See COPYING.txt for license details.
            */

            /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
            ?>

            <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
            <meta property="og:title"
            content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName()) ?>" />
            <meta property="og:image"
            content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()) ?>" />
            <meta property="og:description"
            content="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription()) ?>" />
            <meta property="og:url" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProduct()->getProductUrl()) ?>" />
            <?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE)->getAmount()) :?>
            <meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($priceAmount) ?>"/>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('meta.currency') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```